# Esconder la url o carpeta de origen de una familia tipográfica al público

Tags: css, css3, fuentes

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(../fonts/myFirstFont.woff); //no mostrar
}
```

Me gustaría saber de qué manera ocultar la ruta o **url** de origen de una fuente previamente subida desde el panel de admin, es decir, que el usuario no tenga acceso a esa información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sería ocultar como tal la ubicación, más bien es agregar directrices a tu archivo `.htaccess` si es que estás usando Apache.

Primera opción: Para prevenir que archivos de tipografía se muestren en el listado de archivos.

```
IndexIgnore *.ttf *.woff *.woff2 *.eot, *.otf *.cff *.afm *.lwfn
IndexIgnore *.ffil *.fon *.pfm *.pfb *.svg *.std *.pro *.xsf
```

Lo modificas de acuerdo a las que uses

Segunda opción: Ocultar todo el folder de "fonts":

```
<Directory /ruta/a/fonts>
  Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu respuesta :)